# I am trying to fetch text and image data from local json file in android but it show error

Tags: android, json

I am trying to fetch text and image data from local `JSON` file in android but it shows error...what should I change or add in to above code to let image and text data fetch??

```
public class ActivityKurti extends ListActivity {
String Kurti="kurti";
String Img="img";
String Name="name";
String Prize="prize";
//********************
Context context; // context
Resources resources = context.getResources();
//**************************

JSONArray KArray=null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> KurtiList;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.item_kurti);

    KurtiList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    try
    {
        String line, line1 = "";

        //File fi = new File("sdcard/1.txt");

        //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fi));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("kurti.json")));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            line1 += line;
        }

        //Log.e("json", line1);



        /*JSONObject jOject = new JSONObject(line1);            
        JSONArray jArray = jOject.getJSONArray("countrie");

        String name= "";
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject j = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            name += j.getString("name") + "\n";

            //Log.e("name",j.getString("name"));                
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage(name)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
        .show();*/

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(line1);
        KArray = jo.getJSONArray(Kurti);

        for(int i = 0; i< KArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject ijo = KArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //8888888888888888888888888888888
            String imageName = ijo.getString("img");

            final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(resourceId);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId);


        //888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 

            String nm = ijo.getString(Name);
            String pz = ijo.getString(Prize);

            HashMap<String,String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();

            row.put(Name, nm);
            row.put(Prize, pz);


            //88888888888888888888888888888888
            final int resourceId1 = resources.getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

            row.put("flag", Integer.toString(resourceId1) );
            //8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
            KurtiList.add(row);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter la = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), KurtiList,R.layout.item_kurti, new String[] {Name,Prize,Img}, new int[] {R.id.txtname, R.id.txtprize,R.id.imgkurti});
    setListAdapter(la);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Ship_Info:
            Intent in=new Intent(this,ActivityShipInfo.class);
            startActivity(in);

            return true;

        case R.id.Contact_Us:
            Intent in2=new Intent(this,ActivityContactInfo.class);
            startActivity(in2);

            return true; 

        case R.id.Policies:
            Intent in3=new Intent(this,ActivityPolicies.class);
            startActivity(in3);

            return true;    
        case R.id.Main_menu:
            Intent in1=new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(in1);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error...?

Comment: not sure but do initialize your context, please post the error.

Comment: Post the logcat please. And why have you commented out setContentView() ?

Comment: what is the error please ?

Comment: error is "unfortunately stopped"